# Different Unity animation event at different key frame dispatched at the same time

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, events

I was using unity animation event to handle some issues and I founded two different animation events
at different key frame(one at the beginning and one at the ending) were dispatched at the same time with wrap mode of animation set to **pingpong**.

1. I add an animation event at the beginning and another different at the ending of the same animation clip.
2. I set the wrap mode to **pingpong**.
3. I set this animation component to disabled by default and checked the **playAutomatically**
4. The reason why I set this animation to disabled is that I was trying to use another animaton event to enable it during application running.
5. I founded these two events are dispatched at the same time once this animation component is enabled,but it returned to normal after that.
6. However,I fixed this problem after I unchecked the **playAutomatically** and played it manually in the script when it's enabled.

I wonder why this would happen,does unity animation has some similar bugs like this?